# Query filter with big data from firestore

Tags: ios, swift, database, filter, google-cloud-firestore

How do I avoid writing a lot of code when using a filter using `firestore`?

I use `tableView` and `didSelect` method to collect data to start using the filter
Now I have near 100+ parameters for the filter. And my parameters are in `tableViewCell`. When I collect me need to pass my selected parameters in firestore `query`.

Now my code look like this:

```
protocol FilterTableViewControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {

    func controller(_ controller: FilterTableViewController,
                didSelectCategory childrensInterior: String?,
                imitationKitchenInterior: String?,
                loftInterior: String?,
                retroInterior: String?,
                cycloramaAccessories: String?,
                bedAccessories: String?,
                ...+50 parameters
                bathAccessories: String?,
                fireplaceAccessories: String?,
                swingAccessories: String?,
                LargeWindowsOpporunities: String?,
                minPriceLabel: Int?,
                maxPriceLabel: Int?)
}

class FilterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var sections: [Section] = []

    weak var delegate: FilterTableViewControllerDelegate?

    static func fromStoryboard(delegate: FilterTableViewControllerDelegate? = nil) -> (navigationController: UINavigationController, filtersController: FilterTableViewController) {
        let navController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterViewController") as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navController.viewControllers[0] as! FilterTableViewController
        controller.delegate = delegate
        return (navigationController: navController, filtersController: controller)
    }

    @IBAction func applyButton(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.controller(self, didSelectCategory: childrensInterior,
                             imitationKitchenInterior: imitationKitchenInterior,
                             loftInterior: loftInterior,
                             retroInterior: retroInterior,
                             cycloramaAccessories: cycloramaAccessories,
                             bedAccessories: bedAccessories,
                             ...+50 parameters
                             bathAccessories: bathAccessories,
                             fireplaceAccessories: fireplaceAccessories,
                             swingAccessories: swingAccessories,
                             LargeWindowsOpporunities: LargeWindowsOpporunities,
                             minPriceLabel: Int(minPriceLabel.text!),
                             maxPriceLabel: Int(maxPriceLabel.text!))

        navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

For example right now I'm collecting things one at a time:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.imitationKitchenInterior = "imitationKitchenInterior"
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.loftInterior = "loftInterior"
        }
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.swingAccessories = "swingAccessories"
        }
    }
    and etc...
}
```

How can I not paint the change of each parameter in the `didSelect` method? Or maybe I need to use `dictionary` or `array` to display data in `tableView` and use `dictionary` or `array` to collect data for the pass in `query firestore`? And how I can apply collected data to pass in `query firestore` using minimum code?

Comment: "Now I have near 100+ parameters for filter." What kind of madness is this?!

Comment: @J.Doe Parameters for photostudios, like a `bed`, `kitchen`, `sofa`, `automobile` and etc. Objects for photography, interiors, equipment. A lot of things that are in the halls for photography

Comment: I would rather make an enum with a method: add(filter Filter) { // add parameter }, but thats just another opinion and offtopic for the question